# Java Eclipse NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse

i declared the variable and initialized it but  i still get this error

Code:

```
//Main

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args)  
{

//  Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
//  Random rnd=new Random();
    StuInfo();

}
public static void StuInfo()
{
    Scanner io=new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rnd=new Random();       
    System.out.println("How many students are there?");
    student[] stu = new student[io.nextInt()];
    for (int i = 0; i < stu.length; i++)
    {
        stu[i].age = 5;

    }
}
}

//Student
 public class student {
     int age;
     double[] grade;
     String name;

}
```

Inputs:

4

Error:

> exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at Main.StuInfo(Main.java:39)
>
> at Main.main(Main.java:12)

Comment: `stu[i]` is `null`.

Comment: You need to work on your title game

Comment: stu[i] is not meant to be null it is meant to be 5.... explain please?

Comment: No, I am not going to explain (and not, it is not supposed to be 5), you need to start using a debugger.

Comment: You are access stu [5] . age ... turn to the duplicated question and scroll down to the answer from Makato (*another occurrence of a NullPointerException occurs when one declares an object array, then immediately tries to dereference elements inside of it.*)

Comment: @luk2302 No need for a debugger. Just understand that a freshly created array of objects has **null** slots.

Comment: @GhostCat yes, but a debugger will make OP see that the array contains n null entries. Should not have commented in the first place...

Comment: @luk2302 "Use a debugger" is written down quickly. For a newbie to "pick up" and get there ... could be a lot of confusing work. When he is already using an IDE ... easy. If not, and maybe just using javac on the command line ... not so easy any more.

Comment: It's really a moot point, either way (with or without debugger); this one should have been pretty straightforward. @Newb69420, it's not that we are trying to discourage you, but you really need to learn how to locate the source of a NullPointerException in a 40-line bare-bones program on your own should you wish to continue.

Answer (score 3):

When you create a object array, your array fill null values. So First in your for loop you should define stu[i] = new Student(); then you can write stu[i].age = 5;